# Puppet get value from Deferred function run

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm using a customized version of such Puppet function [vault_lookup](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-vault_lookup) for Vault integration. Changed some logic, to login with AppRole, not with the certs as it was in the original version. And trying to automate Vault installation with this module: [puppet-vault](https://github.com/jsok/puppet-vault).

So, this code from the example works perfectly:

```
$d = Deferred('vault_lookup::lookup', ["secret/test", 'https://vault.hostname:8200'])

node default {
  notify { example :
    message => $d
  }
}
```

But I'm trying to achieve something like that:

```
class { '::vault':
    storage => {
      postgresql => {
        connection_url => "postgres://postgres_user:${d}@IP:5432/vault_db_user",
        ha_enabled     => 'true',
        ha_table       => 'vault_ha_locks',
      }
    }
}
```

And this is content of the variable `$d` inside `::vault class`:

```
Deferred('vault_lookup::lookup', ["secret/test", 'https://vault.hostname:8200'])
```

Yeah, I can get correct content of the variable by using such `call`:

```
connection_url => "postgres://postgres_user:${d.call()}@IP:5432/vault_db_user",
```

It's cool, but I can't use `Sensitive` type on this variable for hiding content inside Puppet run logs :(
Also, I can easily get content of `$d` variable (even with `Sensitive` type) while using standard Puppet resources like `file`.

Maybe someone already implemented `vault_lookup` and can suggest how to pass variable content to other classes inside manifest?

Comment: You should be able to wrap the `Sensitive` function for the associated type around the `Deferred` function i.e. `Sensitive(Deferred('vault_lookup::lookup', ["secret/test", 'https://vault.hostname:8200']))`. Your variable assigned to the return would then both be redacted and interpolate as expected.

Comment: Side note that may be relevant for you is that the whole reason for `Deferred` in this context is that JRuby is incompatible with non-obsolete versions of GnuTLS, so the MRI interpreter is necessary for any secure connection to Vault for read actions. I discovered this when I wrote the first production use Vault bindings for Puppet Enterprise (which coincidentally also leveraged AppRole auth as yours does).

Comment: @MattSchuchard yeap, I can wrap it with `Sensitive` but inside that `::vault` deployment class I will receive such content inside `$d` variable: `"Sensitive [value redacted]"`. I understand that the main problem that the puppet is running `Deferred` function on the agent and classes are being compiled on the master. But maybe there is some workaround to pus that variable inside class with the proper sensitive content.

Comment: Oh right `Sensitive` would invoke prior to `vault_lookup`, so I have it backwards: wrap the `Sensitive` inside the `Deferred` so the value is redacted and the entire stack invocation executes on the client.

Comment: @MattSchuchard also tried with the line from the original version of `vault_lookup` inside the ruby function: `Puppet::Pops::Types::PSensitiveType::Sensitive.new(data)` . I've found some PR, where this issue is already mentioned: [link](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-vault_lookup/pull/21/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R155)